# Intellij IDEA - how to understood which project connected to github and can push, which not push - just local git?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, version-control

I have a couple projects in Intellij IDEA. All used local git. But one use git and connected to github. After this github connection when i check settings (Ctrl+Alt+S -> Version Control), I see my public github account added to it and i see it when opened **any** of my projects!

How to be sure that other projects will not pushed to public repo on github? Because I use the same username and email for all local GITs like for github.

Comment: I think that maybe you need better roots on how git works...take a look for example at how git works within github https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/

Comment: You are right i don't know very well how git or github works. But in this current case I don't know how Intellij Idea work with my git/github accounts.